# Problems with nested while loops in Kotlin

Tags: function, loops, kotlin, while-loop, nested-loops

So I was trying to create a function called `createSquare()` where the first argument is the character used to create the square and the second argument is its side length, should have worked like

```kotlin
createSquare('a', 3)
/* Output is 
aaa
aaa
aaa
*/
```

I tried using the *while* loop to achieve this in the following way.

```
fun createSquare(character: Char = '*', side: Int = 3){
  var i = 0
  var j = 0
  while(i < side){
    while(j < side){
      print(character)
      ++j
    }
    print('\n')
    ++i
  } 
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  createSquare() // Default arguments passed
}
```

And this is how I thought the nested while loops would work:

1. Execute the inner while loop
2. Linespace moves the output cursor to the next line
3. `i` increments by 1
4. Steps 1-3 happen again till  `i` becomes 3, stopping the whole nested loop

However this is the output instead:

```
*** //Output

/*
Where I expected


***
***
***

*/
```

There might be silly errors in my code as yet I'm a novice programmer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't reset `j` after inner loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more "kotliny" way to write those loops would be to use ranges:

```kotlin
for (i in 0..side) {
  // your code
}
```

or

```kotlin
repeat(side) { i -> 
  // your code
}
```

or

```kotlin
(0..side).forEach { i ->
  // your code
}
```

- This has the benefit (and downside) of not leaking the counter
- These will all essentially compile down to a for-loop in bytecode

Of course you can loop manually too, but evidently, that is error-prone